# How can I make my program exit a loop when the user inputs a specific keyword?

Tags: java

I was wondering how I could make my program exit a loop when the user inputs a specific keyword? I have already figured out how to do this with integers, but I want to know how to incorporate this with Strings.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        while (true) {
            System.out.println("type words.");
            System.out.println("type stop to exit the program.");
            String uInput = input.nextLine();


            if (uInput == "STOP") {
                System.out.println("exit successful");
                break; 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use equals function. uInput.equals("STOP");